# Staging of several android devices made simple

Tags: scripts, multiple-devices

I have to stage several android dongles to comply to my company’s need. I need to setup the WiFi, google account, download 3/4 apps, configure them, change background picture... i’v been Trying to find a script/macro that would do that for me. Apps such as MacroDroid requires that I setup the dongles anyway. I wonder if there would be an option to copy this macro to the dongle using the sd card and let it do the job. Ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I've just stumbled upon a project at Github, and remembered your question here. It seems like **[inception](https://github.com/tgalal/inception)** should perfectly fit your needs (except for the Google account, maybe, where it's a bad idea anyway to use the same one for all your employees). Quoting from the project description:

> Inception is a set of tools for auto configuring android devices. You can do the following:
>
> - Include any apps to be (pre)installed
> - Remove any stock apps
> - Root the device
> - Install busybox
> - Configure Wifi networks
> - Generate all device settings
> - Patch APKs
> - Replace Kernel, and/or ramdisk data in both boot and recovery imgs
> - Place your adb keys, configure USB debugging

Most of this you'd probably not even need (rooting, patching APKs, replacing the kernel, prepare ADB, installing Busybox). But what you wrote is covered.

*Inception* requires a Python installation on your computer. After initializing your "project" and adjusting the configuration to your needs (incl. placing the `.apk` files you want to install), it creates an `update.zip` you can flash via the device's [recovery-mode](/questions/tagged/recovery-mode) (which usually will require a custom recovery). Optionally, it also can generate a cache partition img for your device, allowing you to deploy your update in bootloader/download mode.

I have not tried it, so I cannot tell how good it is – but it sounds like it's at least worth a look.