# Enable USB debugging through recovery mode and ADB sideload

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, usb-debugging, locked-out

This is a follow-up question to [Apply update from ADB: how to use it when you are locked out of the device](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/230996/202005). Basically, I intend to somehow use this command to remove the lock screen:

```
adb sideload customROM.zip
```

But, the `customROM.zip` should be something like described [here](https://www.isrgrajan.com/how-to-enable-usb-debugging-in-android-using-recovery-mode.html) to enable USB debugging. The problem is, those steps are incomplete:

> **Steps to Enable USB Debugging Using Recovery Mode**
>
> - Unzip the stock ROM.
> - Within the extracted folder, you will find the **system.img** well extract it too using Ext4 Unpacker
> - Also, extract the **Update-SuperSU.v1.65.zip** file.
> - Now open the folder where you have extracted the **system.img** files
> - Grab any **.apk** file from this folder and change the extension from **.apk** to **.zip**
> - And Copy the **RSA Certificated** to the **Update-SuperSU.v1.65** folder (delete previous files if exist)
> - Also, copy the **build.prop** to the system folder located within **Update-SuperSU.v1.65** folder
> - Locate the **update-script** file within this folder and edit it using **Notepad++**
> - You need to update the **build.prop** file after adding the following line at the bottom
>   `persist.service.adb.enable=1`
> - Next step is updating **SQLite** Database
> - Which can be done by adding the following code to the update-script file
>   `sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db "UPDATE global SET value=1 WHERE name='adb_enabled'"`
>
> Cheers! You have Enabled USB Debugging
> Now you can install your custom or stock ROM using ADB – USB Debugging

Although the above steps seem **incomplete**, they look convincing that there might be a way to modify a stock ROM to enable USB debugging by:

```
adb sideload modified-stock-ROM-which-just-enables-USB-debugging-and-does-nothing-else.zip
```

Is there any better explanation than [those steps](https://www.isrgrajan.com/how-to-enable-usb-debugging-in-android-using-recovery-mode.html)?

Comment: A non-rooted stock device should not allow to install unsigned updates. As it is a Samsung device this may be a bit different (unlocking and flashing e.g. via Odin is different to most Android devices) but at least when booting first time after making your changes the device should clear all user data because of the manipulation. As I wrote in your last post the best way is to perform a factory reset.

Comment: @Robert Right, but factory reset erases all data. I just want to keep phone camera photos and videos =)

Comment: And the device PIN/pattern has been designed to protect those images from "unauthorized access" (authorized is the person who knows the PIN). I understand that this not what you want to hear. Also keep in mind that the files should be encrypted which means that even if you manage to bypass the lock screen you might still not have access to the files.

Comment: we can only tell you what is **not** possible https://android.stackexchange.com/q/227110

Comment: this is **closest** to what you want. injecting a script via flashing whole cache partition from heimdall/odin which can do modifications from stock recovery (like enable usb-debugging and authorize adb). but this is long outdated and modern samsung devices **not supported** https://android.stackexchange.com/q/186907

Comment: if someone knows if it is possible (or not) to exploit your device on locked bootloader then it's user [elliwigy](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=4006249&page=24) but believe me that whole stuff you found is all outdated, there is no hope in 2020. this is how i did on another ancient device https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2965462

Answer (score 2):

Do those steps above. However, when you get adb access on the phone, use it to `rm` the `gesture` or `passwd` file located in `/system/system_ext/etc/passwd`. This will remove the lock when you use it. Just input anything and it will let you in, which will then unencrypt your files as well.

This is the solution to the best of my knowledge, it's possible I may be incorrect but I think it will work.

Comment: I don't have the phone any longer. So, I cannot double-check your approach. Maybe someone can test it later :)