# Adb refuses to see my phone, lsusb has no problems

Tags: adb, fastboot, usb-debugging

After installing `android-tools-adb` and `android-tools-fastboot` from a `ppa` and adding:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev", SYMLINK+="android%n"
```

to `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` (plus `chmod a+r ...`), and `0x18d1` to `~/.android/adb_usb.ini`, after issuing:

```
$ sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
$ sudo service udev restart
$ sudo udevadm trigger
```

`adb devices` still refuses to see anything (with or without `sudo`). It doesn't matter if I start with <kbd>VolUp</kbd> in `Recovery mode`, or not, nothing happens (restarts included). The problem is, somewhere along the road I performed a factory reset, so now I'm stuck on the FRP screen (papers, along with the darn PIN, not available anymore). Since `lsusb` has no problems, I have to deduce that the cable is not the problem. However, `fastboot` seems to work (if I get into the menu), but I can't do anything with it.

Unfortunately, USB debugging was not enabled prior to this, and from what I read there is a way to enable it, but that implies `adb` seeing my phone (as if with a "broken screen"). OTOH, by and large I see that USB debugging *must* be enabled in order for `adb` to work. That's very confusing.

I'm out of ideas. Is there anything else that can be done? Contacting seller & co are out of the question -- this was a gift, long time ago, moved out.

Comment: AFAIK you can't run `adb`without enabling user debugging Even if you could you are stuck with [FRP not allowing you to log into your device](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/127739/how-to-bypass-factory-reset-protection-frp-or-verify-your-account-screen)

Comment: @beeshyams One of the several answers I found was [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/112040/how-to-enable-usb-debugging-in-android-if-forgotten-pattern-for-screen-unlock). There were several others in the same line but, it's also true that the majority of the answers seemed to agree with you. However, you can see the confusion. Because if it is possible then flashing should be possible from the recovery menu (don't care about the FRP). But, if I knew... Also, in that answer it says to mount `data` but that no longer exists due to factory reset, I think (bummer).

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen The mentioned adb commands in those answers are to be used with a custom recovery ROM with adb support. Such a custom ROM requires an bootloader unlocked device.

Comment: @beeshyams In the meantime I found [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/230999) but, even if I can't find the RSA Certificate, as the post in there mentions, it seems incomplete: why go through the trouble of modifying the SU Update thing if nothing happens with it? And if it does, what? Because in the recovery menu, if I issue `Apply update from ADB`, `adb` can see the phone as "sideload". So, some hopes?